# Printing a list vertically with pprint

Tags: python, pprint

I try to use pprint to print a list:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> a = [1, 3, 6, 8, 0]
>>> pprint.pprint(a)
[1, 3, 6, 8, 0]
>>>
```

why not this

```
[1,
3,
6,
8,
0]
```

look forward you answer! THANKS!

Comment: Why *should* the list be printed vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter), it appears that you need to specifiy the `width` of your input which is set to `80` by default. You may try the following

```
>>> stuff = ['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni']
>>> pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4, width=50)
>>> pp.pprint(stuff)
['spam', 'eggs', 'lumberjack', 'knights', 'ni']
>>> pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4, width=1)
>>> pp.pprint(stuff)
[   'spam',
    'eggs',
    'lumberjack',
    'knights',
    'ni']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use width parameter:

```
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=4)
pp.pprint(a)
```